# How can I make the header maintain its position and not grow as the text grows?

Tags: html, css, header

So, I have a header on black background, and I don't want to grow that header background size as the text grows.
Here is the code:

```html
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <nav class="nav">
            <a href="#">Test 1</a>
            <a href="#">Test 2</a>
            <a href="#">Test 3</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
```

css:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.header {
    background: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
}

.nav {
    font-size: 60px;
}
```

Comment: you could make use of ```max-width``` and ```max-height``` css properties.

Answer (score -1):

Add height to the header

```
.header { 
        background: black;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 30px;
        height: 80px
    }
```